# making a sieve for an expensive for loop

Tags: rust, optimization, sieve

I'm trying to write code that is done over a lot of values, and my code is doing a ton of extra work. I'm not even quite sure mathematically how to describe the values I want to skip, because as `i` gets larger I want to skip a larger and larger percentage of `i`s.

it will be easiest to explain with psudocode:

```
f(n)
    while n > 0
        if 32 < n%250 < 129 do work, else discard
        n = floor( n/250 )
        
g(n)
    while n > 0
        if n%3 == 0 do work, else discard
        n = floor( n/288 )

main()
    for i in range
        print f(i) and g(i) if neither function hits discard & both same total # of loops
```

I want a `range` that wastes as little computation as possible. the optimizations I've been able to think of so far are using `(0..n).step_by(3)` to at least make the first loop of `g(n)` will always be good, and running+checking `f(n)` first so you don't need to run `g(n)` if it hits discard. what I'm looking for is a way to define a range similarly to how `.step_by(3)` only tries values that work for the first loop of `g(n)` for all the loops in the `while`s. optimally, I would like to not need any if statements in the `while` loops at all and instead have a range that only tries successful values.

basically what I'm asking is if there's a way to try fewer values so that the big O of the code is something to do with to 91 instead of 250 and 288 (or if you can incorporate some logic from the final if and bring it even lower than 91 that'd be awesome). I'm getting correct outputs, but it is taking a very long time. I am trying to run this on as large a range as possible; end goal would be to run it up to values  on the order of 250^40==8.27e95==2^319.7, so determining which values are skippable before needing to run the functions would save a large amount of computation.

to help me make sense of describing the values I want, I have drawn a grid for valid values only considering the g(n) case and with smaller numbers [`n%2` and `floor(n/6)`]. the highlighted full blue columns are the numbers that would go through in this case and the highlighted white rows are the points where the values are discarded.
[image: grid of numbers with cases that make it through highlighted]
here's the same thing but with [`n%3` and `floor(n/6)`]
[image: basically looks the same as the other one]
here's the f(n) function but with `1<n%6<4`
[image]

if you want to look at the full code or recommend any other optimizations you can see that below as well:

```rust
use arrayvec::ArrayVec;
fn main() {
    'outer: for n in (0..18446744073709551615u64).step_by(3) { //2^64-1; make smaller if you want the code to finish
        let mut base250: ArrayVec<u8, 8> = ArrayVec::new(); //using ArrayVec makes reallocation slowdowns go away
        let mut tmp:u8;
        let mut m = n;
        while m > 0 { //f(n) of the psudocode; inlined here
            tmp = (m%250).try_into().unwrap(); //type goes from u64(n) into u8(tmp)
            if tmp-33 < 96 { //takes advantage of uint rollover to just do 1 comparison
                base250.push(tmp-1);
            } else { continue 'outer; } //condition broke; discard this run and try the next value
            m /= 250;
        }
        m = n;
        let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 8> = ArrayVec::new();
        while m > 0 { //g(n) of the psudocode; inlined here
            if m%3==0 {
                base288.push((m/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap()); //type goes from u64(n) into u8(t)
            } else { continue 'outer; } //condition broke; discard this run and try the next value
            m /= 288;
        }
        base250.reverse();
        if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a==b).count() > 3 { //checks how many values are matching
            let long:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if c == 127u8 {'¶'} // convert the vector to a string
                                                  else if c == 32u8 {'█'} // with readable newlines and spaces
                                                  else {c.try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
            let short:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if c == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                  else if c == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                  else {c.try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
            println!("{long}   {short}   {n}");
        }
    }
}
```

a commenter suggested I try saving the vector one value at a time to get rid of the while loops, but since the while loops are much smaller than the for loop I think it is more worthwhile to try to do fewer big loops. I tried implementing it, but it is much slower on all ranges my computer can run; here it is anyways if you have any suggestions that would speed it up. mathematically, this code is identical to the previous code; ie it gives the exact same output. I've seen places saying that the `.clone()` call is expensive but I don't know enough about `*` and `&` to get it to compile without a `.clone()`

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut base250known: HashMap<u64, ArrayVec<u8>> = HashMap::from([(0u64,ArrayVec::new())]);
    let mut base288known: HashMap<u64, ArrayVec<u8>> = HashMap::from([(0u64,ArrayVec::new())]);
    for n in 1..18446744073709551615u64 {
        let mut check: bool = true;
        if n%250-33 < 96 {
            match base250known.get(&(n/250)) { 
                Some(old) => {
                    let mut new = old.clone();
                    new.push((n%250-1).try_into().unwrap()); 
                    base250known.insert(n,new);
                    },
                None => { check = false; }
            };
        } else { check = false; }
        if n%3==0 {
            match base288known.get(&(n/288)) {
                Some(old) => {
                    let mut new = old.clone();
                    new.push((n/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
                    base288known.insert(n,new);
                },
                None => { check = false; }
            };
        } else { check = false; } 
        if check { if base250known[&n].iter().zip(base288known[&n].iter().rev()).filter(|&(a,b)| a==b).count() >= 0 {
            let long:String = base250known[&n].iter().map(|&c|{if c == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                                else if c == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                                else {c.try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
            let short:String = base288known[&n].iter().rev().map(|&c|{if c == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                                    else if c == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                                    else {c.try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
            println!("{long}   {short}   {n}");   }   }   }   }
```

Comment: You might wanna make a digit Iterator to avoid those string allocations if benchmarks agree strongly with me

Comment: @MeetTitan woah, maybe I came off sounding like I know more than I actually do. I've never heard of a specific thing called a digit iterator; google brings up iterating through the literal digits of a number in a given base but I don't see in what way that would help me? with the string allocations, are you saying it's better to return `Vec<u8>` and only convert it to a string right before the `println!`? what do you mean by 'benchmarks'; are you saying use something analogous to python's timeit to test various parts and if so how?

Comment: Well it wouldn't reduce the big o complexity of your algo, but reducing String usage (which is just a `Vec<u8>`) which allocates memory from the heap might increase performance depending on how tight the loop actually is. A digit Iterator would just be a custom Iterator that iterates over the digits of your integer by dividing by 10 in a loop until 0 instead of turning it into a String (allocating to heap) and iterating on chars.

Comment: Check out [criterion](https://docs.rs/criterion/latest/criterion/) for benchmarking (does build A do the thing faster than build B?), and read the [Rust Performance Book](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/heap-allocations.html) on why you might want to avoid heap allocations

Comment: Maybe also "The Stack and The Heap" in [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html)

Comment: @MeetTitan  I think I understand what you're saying now. as far as I know, I'm not looping over any `Strings`, just converting the char codes to a string when I'm done generating them. after quickly attempting the swap to returning `Vec<u8>`s out of the functions and only converting after the last `if` there did seem to take like 3/4 the time for 10^10. I'll go read through those links now.

Comment: Memoization might be another low hanging performance fruit. If you save `n MOD x` when you calculate it, you can reuse it in the future. In other words: can you reuse the (inner, intermediate) results of `modX()` for future runs? Calculating `modX()` 123 should be computationally similar to `modX()` 1234

Comment: @MeetTitan what do you mean by save/how would I implement that? wouldn't each loop be taking the mod of a new value? or are you saying swap out the three `n%250`s in the first function to a `let m = n%250`?

Comment: Check out [the wikipedia article on memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), they explain it better than I ever could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a self-answer, and a bad one, but I technically got the code to do what I said I wanted. essentially, this makes the first check the range, so each time the while would have looped in the original code I just make a new for loop. after creating the range, the second check becomes a filter which I broke out into a second function living at the end of the code. as long as you create enough loops to catch the whole range it's the same code.

```
use arrayvec::ArrayVec;
use itertools::iproduct;

fn main() {
    for a in (33u64..129u64).filter(|a| acceptable(&[a])) {
            let mut raw: u64 = a;
            let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 1> = ArrayVec::new();
            while raw > 0 {
                base288.push((raw/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
                raw /= 288;
            }
            let base250: ArrayVec<u8, 1> = ArrayVec::from([a.try_into().unwrap()]);

            if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() >= 0 {
                let s:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if (c-1) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c-1) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c-1).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let t:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if (c) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let n: u64 = a;
                println!("{s}   {t}   {n}");
            }
        }
    println!("1 digit");
    for (b,a) in (iproduct![33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64]).filter(|(b,a)| acceptable(&[a,b])) {
            let mut raw: u64 = (b)*250u64 + (a);
            let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 2> = ArrayVec::new();
            while raw > 0 {
                base288.push((raw/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
                raw /= 288;
            }
            let base250: ArrayVec<u8, 2> = ArrayVec::from([b.try_into().unwrap(),a.try_into().unwrap()]);

            if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() > 0 {
                let s:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if (c-1) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c-1) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c-1).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let t:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if (c) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let n: u64 = (b)*250u64 + (a);
                println!("{s}   {t}   {n}");
            }
        }
    println!("2 digits");
    for (c,b,a) in (iproduct![33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64]).filter(|(c,b,a)| acceptable(&[a,b,c])) {
            let mut raw: u64 = (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
            let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 3> = ArrayVec::new();
            while raw > 0 {
                base288.push((raw/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
                raw /= 288;
            }
            let base250: ArrayVec<u8, 3> = ArrayVec::from([c.try_into().unwrap(),b.try_into().unwrap(),a.try_into().unwrap()]);

            if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() > 1 {
                let s:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if (c-1) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c-1) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c-1).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let t:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if (c) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let n: u64 = (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
                println!("{s}   {t}   {n}");
            }
        }
    println!("3 digits");
    for (d,c,b,a) in (iproduct![33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64]).filter(|(d,c,b,a)| acceptable(&[a,b,c,d])) {
            let mut raw: u64 = (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
            let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 4> = ArrayVec::new();
            while raw > 0 {
                base288.push((raw/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
                raw /= 288;
            }
            let base250: ArrayVec<u8, 4> = ArrayVec::from([d.try_into().unwrap(),c.try_into().unwrap(),b.try_into().unwrap(),a.try_into().unwrap()]);

            if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() > 2 {
                let s:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if (c-1) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c-1) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c-1).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let t:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if (c) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let n: u64 = (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
                println!("{s}   {t}   {n}");
            }
        }
    println!("4 digits");
    for (e,d,c,b,a) in (iproduct![33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64]).filter(|(e,d,c,b,a)| acceptable(&[a,b,c,d,e])) {
            let mut raw: u64 = (e)*250u64.pow(4) + (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
            let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 5> = ArrayVec::new();
            while raw > 0 {
                base288.push((raw/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
                raw /= 288;
            }
            let base250: ArrayVec<u8, 5> = ArrayVec::from([e.try_into().unwrap(),d.try_into().unwrap(),c.try_into().unwrap(),b.try_into().unwrap(),a.try_into().unwrap()]);

            if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() > 3 {
                let s:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if (c-1) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c-1) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c-1).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let t:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if (c) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let n: u64 = (e)*250u64.pow(4) + (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
                println!("{s}   {t}   {n}");
            }
        }
    println!("5 digits");
    for (f,e,d,c,b,a) in (iproduct![33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64]).filter(|(f,e,d,c,b,a)| acceptable(&[a,b,c,d,e,f])) {
            let mut raw: u64 = (f)*250u64.pow(5) + (e)*250u64.pow(4) + (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
            let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 6> = ArrayVec::new();
            while raw > 0 {
                base288.push((raw/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
                raw /= 288;
            }
            let base250: ArrayVec<u8, 6> = ArrayVec::from([f.try_into().unwrap(),e.try_into().unwrap(),d.try_into().unwrap(),c.try_into().unwrap(),b.try_into().unwrap(),a.try_into().unwrap()]);

            if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() > 4 {
                let s:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if (c-1) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c-1) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c-1).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let t:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if (c) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                    else if (c) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                    else {(c).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
                let n: u64 = (f)*250u64.pow(5) + (e)*250u64.pow(4) + (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
                println!("{s}   {t}   {n}");
            }
        }
    println!("6 digits");
    for (g,f,e,d,c,b,a) in (iproduct![33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64]).filter(|(g,f,e,d,c,b,a)| acceptable(&[a,b,c,d,e,f,g])) {
        let mut raw: u64 = (g)*250u64.pow(6) + (f)*250u64.pow(5) + (e)*250u64.pow(4) + (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
        let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 7> = ArrayVec::new();
        while raw > 0 {
            base288.push((raw/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
            raw /= 288;
        }
        let base250: ArrayVec<u8, 7> = ArrayVec::from([g.try_into().unwrap(),f.try_into().unwrap(),e.try_into().unwrap(),d.try_into().unwrap(),c.try_into().unwrap(),b.try_into().unwrap(),a.try_into().unwrap()]);

        if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() > 5 {
            let s:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if (c-1) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                else if (c-1) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                else {(c-1).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
            let t:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if (c) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                else if (c) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                else {(c).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
            let n: u64 = (g)*250u64.pow(6) + (f)*250u64.pow(5) + (e)*250u64.pow(4) + (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
            println!("{s}   {t}   {n}");
        }
    }
    println!("7 digits");
    for (h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a) in (iproduct![33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64,33u64..129u64]).filter(|(h,g,f,e,d,c,b,a)| acceptable(&[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h])) {
        let mut raw: u64 = (h)*250u64.pow(7) + (g)*250u64.pow(6) + (f)*250u64.pow(5) + (e)*250u64.pow(4) + (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
        let mut base288: ArrayVec<u8, 8> = ArrayVec::new();
        while raw > 0 {
            base288.push((raw/3%96+32).try_into().unwrap());
            raw /= 288;
        }
        let base250: ArrayVec<u8, 8> = ArrayVec::from([h.try_into().unwrap(),g.try_into().unwrap(),f.try_into().unwrap(),e.try_into().unwrap(),d.try_into().unwrap(),c.try_into().unwrap(),b.try_into().unwrap(),a.try_into().unwrap()]);

        if base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() > 6 {
            let s:String = base250.iter().map(|&c|{if (c-1) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                else if (c-1) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                else {(c-1).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
            let t:String = base288.iter().map(|&c|{if (c) == 127u8 {'¶'}
                                                else if (c) == 32u8 {'█'}
                                                else {(c).try_into().unwrap()} }).collect();
            let n: u64 = (h)*250u64.pow(7) + (g)*250u64.pow(6) + (f)*250u64.pow(5) + (e)*250u64.pow(4) + (d)*250u64.pow(3) + (c)*250u64.pow(2) + (b)*250u64 + (a);
            println!("{s}   {t}   {n}");
        }
    }
    println!("8 digits");
    fn acceptable (nums: &[&u64]) -> bool {
        let mut raw: u64 = 0;
        for i in 0..nums.len() { raw += nums[i] * 250u64.pow(i.try_into().unwrap()); }
        while raw > 0 { if raw%3==0 { raw /= 288; } else { return false; } }
        return true;
    }
}
```

the code is stupidly repetitive and very long, so I feel like it should be able to be rewritten to be one loop of the form

```
for j in (1..) {
    for a in (iproduct!(33u64..129u64 j times)).filter(|j variables| acceptable(&[j variables backwards]) {
}
```

and so on but I do not know how to phrase that in rust. I still welcome any more comments about speeding things up, especially for this check here:

```
base250.iter().zip(base288.iter()).filter(|&(a,b)| a-1==*b).count() > j
```

because I suspect that this is a significant amount of the work that the computer is doing. I'm just trying to check for similarity between the two vecs, if you know a faster way to check for 'close but not necessarily exact', even if it is a different implementation of that concept from this line, I'd be very grateful.